# difference between "any influence over sb" and "any influence on sb"

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

I wonder if I can replace ***over*** with ***on*** in the sentence below and if the meaning remains the same. If there is any difference, I would like to ask for the explanation of it.

> Her parents no longer have any real influence **over** her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expressions have little to distinguish them but **influence over** is more likely to be used in a parent-child or similar context and in a person to person situation.

You will come across statements such as: **Her adolescent son is running wild and his mother no longer has any influence over him.**

**Influence on** might be used in situations concerning a person, a group, an organisation or a decision.

Given that the two expressions overlap, it really comes down to context and preference.

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **influence on** is several times more popular than **influence over**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: May I ask you to let me double-check again the specific example sentence case? *Her parents no longer have any real influence **over** her.* *Her parents no longer have any real influence **on** her.* The second one is also right and can be used naturally, doesn't it? But I guess from your explanation, in this person to person case, the first one is more used and preferred, but there is nothing wrong with using the second expression instead.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Exactly!